# How to specify language for a week input element in HTML5?

Tags: html, internationalization, standards

Is there any way to display the Spanish text "Semana" instead of "Week", and change the day names to spanish in the html5 input week element?

This doesn't work:

```
<input lang="es" type="week" />
```

Neither does setting it in the html main tag.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be the browser that sets this based on the language that it's set to. Is it really necessary to override the language in that case?

Comment: Let me check with another browser

Comment: It may not be possible to change this at all. But usually, the user's browser language will be their preferred language anyway, so are you sure you really need tobe able to change it? Also I imagine there may be browsers out there that don't *have* other languages available except the one they come in

Comment: All my browsers are in english -.- I'll try tomorrow with another computer. Thank you. The reason for this is that ALL of the users will need the spanish text.

Comment: Yeah, I see. You *may* need to move to a 3rd party jQuery based component, and do all the translations yourself, to do that (which would be a shame, of course, because of all the added complexity...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing - haven't tried it but I'd have thought:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: Already tried but didn't work. Still displaying things in english. I'll try tomorrow with a browser installed in spanish.